# Get only the body of an HTML email in PHP

Tags: php, regex, email

So I have a PHP script which takes in piped emails, appends a footer to them and passes them on.

But if someone sends an email which is already in HTML format it just inserts the entire html email into the body of a new html document.
I need a script which will (if the email is already in HTML) take off the html, head and body tags leaving the original email.

I.e. if someone sent an email

```
<html><body>This is my awesome input email which is <strong>already</strong> in HTML</body></html>
```

It is parsed by my script to become

```
<html><body><html><body>This is my awesome input email which is <strong>already</strong> in HTML</body></html></body></html>
```

How can I get it to take off the HTML structure if it exists?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it's possible to detect if the `html` element is present when working with DOMDocument and HTML because `loadHTML()` will add its own `html` element if it is not present.

The code below will just always return the serialised HTML of the `body` element.

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;

$dom->loadHTML($html);

$body = '';

foreach($dom->getElementsByTagName('body')->item(0)->childNodes as $child) {
    $body .= $dom->saveHTML($child);
}
```

[CodePad](http://codepad.viper-7.com/EMnyVT).

Alternatively, you could treat the HTML as XML and then detect it, but without a `documentElement` you may have problems. I solved that by adding a dummy `documentElement`, though it's a bit clunky (I'd probably stick to the above code myself).

```
// Need a documentElement so wrap it with some generic garbage.
$html = '<garbage>' . $html . '</garbage>';

$dom = new DOMDocument;

$dom->loadXML($html);

if ($dom->getElementsByTagName('html')->length) {
   ...
}
```

[CodePad](http://codepad.viper-7.com/97r7Rm).

Comment: I ran that and got `Warning: DOMDocument::saveHTML() expects exactly 0 parameters, 1 given in #### : eval()'d code on line 12`

Comment: @MitchellGrice: Are you using an older version of PHP? If so, replace `saveHTML($child)` with `saveXML($child, LIBXML_NOEMPTYTAG)`.

Comment: I'm using 5.2.16
The change in your comment works perfectly, thanks for your help